# How can I find the possible phase shifts (C) of a sine function given amplitude, midline, and frequency?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, graphing-functions

Ex $P(t)=2.95\cdot \sin[(\frac{\pi}{6})(x+C)]+3.15$

So to find the phase shift I would look for the lesser of the two infinite pairs of input points because these will give me points that begin one of the cycles of a positive sine function. So to do this I make $P(t)$ equal to the mid line or $P(t)= 2.95$

As I solve I'll get stuck with having to solve for $x+C$:

$2.95=2.95\cdot \sin[(\frac{\pi}{6})(x+C)]+3.15$

$-0.2=2.95\cdot \sin[(\frac{\pi}{6})(x+C)]$

$(\frac{-0.2}{2.95})= \sin[(\frac{\pi}{6})(x+C)]$

$\sin^{-1}(\frac{-0.2}{2.95})=(\frac{\pi}{6})(x+C)$

$(\frac{6}{\pi})[\sin^{-1}(\frac{-0.2}{2.95})]=x+C$

Comment: Why don't you write in the question the equations you want to solve ? This will makes things easier to you and we could explain using your words and equations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've provided my example, but I'm still stumped. I know I can find a regression (there were also given points), but my professor wants an algebraic solution, not a graphical one.

Comment: This is very difficult to read. Use MathJax, please.

Comment: What is MathJax, and how do I use it?

Comment: I edited your question using MathJax. It may take a while to show up.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to use MathJax to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{6}{\pi}\sin^{-1}\frac{-0.2}{2.95} = -.12958$

For $C = 0$, when $x = -.12958, P(t) = 2.95$

A $C$ value will shift the $2.95$ point to the left by +C and to the right by -C. So if you wanted to bring the $2.95$ point onto the $y$ axis $(x = 0)$, make $C = -.12958$

That is $P(t) = 2.95\cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}{6}(x - .12958))+3.15$

When $x = 0, P(t) = 2.95$

Comment: When I graph the regressed curve, y=2.95 when x is approximately -2.029, 9.971, etc. In the regression C was about 1.89974

Comment: So how can I manually find C with regressions and how can I prove this phase shift algebraically?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what your goal is. Adjusting the value C shifts the graph horizontally to wherever you want it to be. A value $C$ in the above function will shift the graph so that function values that were previously paired with $x$ are now paired with $x + C$ or $x - C$. For $y = x^2$, when $x = 3, y = 9$. For $y = (x + 3)^2, y = 9 $ will correspond with the previous $x$ shifted to the left by $3$, That is $x = 3 - 3 = 0$ and hence $y = (0 + 3)^2 = 9$ This is a basic axiom of functions.